# How to cancel `edebug-defun`?

Tags: debugging, edebug

How do I undo the effects of `edebug-defun`?  In other words, how do I rescind the directive that causes `edebug` to enter debugging mode when a particular function is invoked?

Also, I'd really like to know where the answer to this question is in the documenation.  I've looked for it far longer than one would think would be necessary...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From `(info "(elisp) Instrumenting")` :

```
   To remove instrumentation from a definition, simply re-evaluate its
definition in a way that does not instrument.  There are two ways of
evaluating forms that never instrument them: from a file with `load',
and from the minibuffer with `eval-expression' (`M-:').
```

IOW, the easy way is to use `C-M-x` without prefix argument (or with a prefix argument, if you have `edebug-all-defs` set).

Comment: Thanks!  After seeing the answer, I am now absolutely certain that the only way I would have found the answer would have been a linear search through all of the Emacs and Elisp documentation.

Comment: FWIW I wish there was an easy way to remove instrumentation from _all_ definitions (even if scattered across multiple files) at once, but I don't know of one.

Comment: @kjo I found it by opening up the edebug section in the elisp manual, and browsing through the sections. Knowing that "effects of edebug-defun" is called "instrumenting" certainly helped.

Comment: @kjo Also, if you report a bug (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) by saying what you actually tried when looking for your answer, the documentation can then be improved.

Answer (score 10):

> In other words, how do I rescind the directive that causes edebug to enter debugging mode when a particular function is invoked?

You can get this effect without removing instrumentation by setting `edebug-initial-mode` to `go`.  This way, you will only get stopped in edebug if there is a breakpoint set.  As of Emacs 25.1, you can do this quickly with `edebug-set-initial-mode`: <kbd><kbd>C-x C-a C-m</kbd> g</kbd>

[`(info "(elisp) Edebug Execution Modes")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug-Execution-Modes.html)

> ```
> ‘g’
>      Go: run until the next breakpoint (‘edebug-go-mode’).  *Note
>      Breakpoints::.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> When you enter a new Edebug level, the initial execution mode comes
> from the value of the variable ‘edebug-initial-mode’ (*note Edebug
> Options::).  By default, this specifies step mode.
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> Command: edebug-set-initial-mode
>
> This command, bound to C-x C-a C-m, sets edebug-initial-mode. It
> prompts you for a key to indicate the mode. You should enter one of
> the eight keys listed above, which sets the corresponding mode.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using [doom emacs](https://github.com/doomemacs/) to cancel `edebug-defun` put your cursor inside defun and run `<leader> m e d` or `eval-defun` (this is equivalent to `C-M-x` mentioned in the accepted answer). Evaluating function definition again "overwrites" edebug's effects.